# belongs_to relation not firing after_update when nullify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In the project i'm working on i have 2 models, user.rb and job.rb.

The user model is related to job, a user can have many job requests and a user can be hired in many jobs but only one user per job can be hired.

User.rb:

```rb
  has_many :job, dependent: :nullify, :foreign_key => "hired_contractor_id"
```

Job.rb:

```rb
  belongs_to :hired_contractor, class_name: "User", optional: true
```

Expected behaviour:
When a user is deleted (which that user is hired in a job) i want to change the job status.

For that i'm trying with after_update or after_save but none is fired by a nullify effect on a belongs_to relation.

What am i mising?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing the `dependent: :nullify` because i found that it doesn't trigger any parent callback.

If you try to update every job in a before_destroy (user.rb) you will not find any job because the relation is gone.

My solution was to remove `dependent: :nullify` so i still have the job relations to find them in a before_destroy on user.rb and update every job :status and :hired_contractor_id columns manally.

Not the best solution but one that works finally.